# How to reset fields of form in Ajax form submiting in Yii 1

Tags: javascript, html, yii

I have following code in my view file:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                            'id'=>'contact',
                            'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                            'htmlOptions'=>array('onsubmit'=>"return false;",
                                'onkeypress'=>"if(event.keyCode==13){send();}"
                                ),
                            'clientOptions'=>array(
                                'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                            ),
                        )); ?>
```

Code for sending message:

```
<div class="f_message">
                            <?php echo $form->labelEx($product,'message'); ?>
                            <?php echo $form->textField($product,'message', array('class'=>'footer_text_area')); ?>
                            <?php echo $form->error($product,'message'); ?>
                        </div>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit', array(
                                    'id' => 'f_send',
                                    'onclick'=>'send();',
                                    'style' => 'margin-left:5px;'
                                )) ?>
```

And javaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                        function send()
                        {
                            var data=$("#contact").serialize();

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('/profile/company/contact/view', array('id'=>$model->c_id)); ?>',
                                data:data,
                                success:function(data){
                                    alert("Your Mail has been sent successfully");

                                },
                                error: function(data) { // if error occured
                                    alert("Error occured.please try again");
                                    alert(data);
                                },

                                dataType:'html'
                            });

                        }

                    </script>
```

These codes are responsible for sending message. When user presses submit button it sends message and alert dialog appears whether email has been sent successfully or not. However, it does not reset message field. I need to develop the code which enbales to reset message field after successfully sent. How can I develop it?

Answer (score 0):

Please add `document.getElementById('YOURFORMID').reset();` after the `alert("Your Mail has been sent successfully");` line to reset it only in case it was successful. Replace the `YOURFORMID` with the actual ID that you set in the `<form id="YOURFORMID">` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Plesae type a line `location.reload();` after alert message to reset message field.